# Execute batch file in the middle of protractor test

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, e2e-testing

I write a test for some section of my web application. I need to run batch file (`batch.exe`) in the middle of test running. My test is:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

describe('Sample Test', function () {

    describe('When click on browse', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            browser.get('http://192.168.1.152/public/documents');
            element(by.linkText('upload')).click();
            element(by.css(".dropzone")).click();


            browser.sleep(5000);

            // <---------- **** this place need to run file
            exec('file-upload.exe', function(err, data) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(data.toString());
            });

            element(by.css("button")).click();
        });

        it('Should be', function () {
            expect(element(by.css("span")).getText()).toBe('file uploaded');
        });
    });
});
```

I used `child_process` node module, but it doesn't work? What should I do? Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: *it doesn't work* - what doesn't work? If you rely on its results this obviously won't work correctly because `execFile` is asynchronous. Use `execFileSync`  or promises.

Comment: Please write correct code

Comment: The code for what? You didn't clarify what the problem is.

Comment: I solved problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue with this code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

describe('Sample Test', function () {

    describe('When click on browse', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            browser.get('http://192.168.1.152/public/documents');
            element(by.linkText('upload')).click();
            element(by.css(".dropzone")).click();


            browser.sleep(5000);

            // <---------- **** this place need to run file
             setTimeout(function () {
                execFile('file-upload.exe', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                   if (error) {
                      throw error;
                   }
                   console.log(stdout);
                });
            },3000);

            element(by.css("button")).click();
        });

        it('Should be', function () {
            expect(element(by.css("span")).getText()).toBe('file uploaded');
        });
    });
});
```

Because of execFile run before `beforeAll` function, and I need to pause it for multiple second, I put `execFile` function in `setTimeOut` to make delay.